# data preprocessing tricks for auto-encoder

Tags: machine-learning, data-processing, autoencoder

Recently, I try to use auto-encoder to find anomalies, but some of the input features are count data(e.g. number of clicks or number of shows). Do I need normalizing or scaling before training?

Comment: Have you found the answer ? I am also using auto encoder for anomalies , should i normalize or not ?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely normalize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will.  The most common way to do it is to subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation.  Each one of your click items should be normalized separately.  For example, if you have number of 'nb_click_banner' and 'nb_click_sidebar' you should normalize both independently.  This helps the network train faster, but it also gives all the features the same weighting at the input and doesn't require the network to learn to divide the weights for those by some factor to give it the same effect on the output.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that any kind of numerical feature would require normalization and scale data preprocessing, otherwise you could be in a situation where one feature influences the classification process more than the others simply because of the range of data it can hold.

Comment: Any suggestions of data preprocessing for auto-encoder?